# Как расширить радиус поиска панорамы через API Яндекс карт?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, можно ли расширить зону поиска панорамы через api Яндекс Карт?
Имеется код вызова по координатам, если вблизи этой координаты есть панормама, то она отображается, в противном случае - ошибка. Судя по всему, панорамы ищутся в радиусе макс. 50 метров.
Например, у меня на яндекс карте размещен маркер в центре парка, ближайшее расстрояние до дороги с панорамой около 200 метров. Вариант с ручным изменением координат не подходит, так как они подставляются через php из бд.

```js
var createPlayer = ymaps.panorama.createPlayer('div_id', [55.83403, 37.623370], {
  // Опции панорамы.
  layer: 'yandex#airPanorama'
});
locateRequest.then(
  function(panoramas) {
    if (panoramas.length) {
      // Создание на странице плеера панорам.
      var player = new ymaps.panorama.Player('div_id', panoramas[0], {
        // Опции панорамы. 
        // direction - направление взгляда.
        direction: [0, -50]
      });
    } else {
      console.log("В заданной точке нет панорам.");
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

В целом панорама в API создана для получения конкретного изображения нужного объекта, особенно с учётом того, что [тарификация за такие вызовы пятикратная](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__limits). А случайных неоправданных вызовов разработчики обычно стараются избегать.

А для осознанного вызова панорамы требуется выбрать подходящую точку и ракурс, что никак не стыкуется со случайным выбором точки и направления обзора.

Если нет желания или возможности дополнить базу вполне определёнными панорамными обзорами, можно при отсутствии панорамы пробивать в цикле наличие панорам по углам расширяющегося квадрата, например, пока что-нибудь не найдётся.